# Homework: calculation about differential form

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

Here is the question: Let $\omega = A dy\wedge dz + B dz \wedge dx + C dx \wedge dy$ in $\mathbf{R}^3$, and $d\omega = 0$. Denote
\begin{eqnarray}
\alpha = \int_0^1 tA(tx,ty,tz)dt\cdot(ydz-zdy)\\
+\int_0^1 tB(tx,ty,tz)dt\cdot(zdx-xdz)\\
+\int_0^1 tC(tx,ty,tz)dt\cdot(xdy-ydx).
\end{eqnarray}
Then show that $d\alpha = \omega$.

Can you teach me how to do this calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow the definitions. Write $\alpha$ as $adx+bdy+cdz$, then show that $b_x-a_y=C$ etc. On the way, you will need to use that $d\omega=0$, ie $A_x+B_y+C_z=0$.